# why doesn't the valid method work?

Tags: java

Here is the code that I tried to make using J Creator LE. 
I'm still at beginner at this, I hope u could help me.

```
public class TelNumHelper{
public static void main(String[] Args){
    String input = "1-800-FLO-WERS";
    String output = " ";
    int Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,Key6,Key7,Key8,Key9,Key0;
    Key2 = 2;
    Key3 = 3;
    Key4 = 4;
    Key5 = 5;
    Key6 = 6;
    Key7 = 7;
    Key8 = 8;
    Key9 = 9;
    Key0 = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
        if(input.charAt(i)=='-'){
            output = output + input.charAt(i);
        }else{
            output = output + valid(input.charAt(i));
        }

    }

public static char valid(char input){

            if(input == A||input == B||input == C||input == 2){
                System.out.println(Key2);
            }else if(input == D||input == E||input == F||input == 3){
                System.out.println(Key3);
            }else if(input == G||input == H||input == I||input == 4){
                System.out.println(Key4);
            }else if(input == J||input == K||input == L||input == 5){
                System.out.println(Key5);
            }else if(input == M||input == N||input == O||input == 6){
                System.out.println(Key6);
            }else if(input == P||input == Q||input == R||input == S||input == 7){
                System.out.println(Key7);
            }else if(input == T||input == U||input == V||input == 8){
                System.out.println(Key8);
            }else if(input == W||input == X||input == Y||input == Z||input == 9){
                    System.out.println(Key9);
            }else if(input == 0){
                System.out.println(Key0);

            }else{
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

}

How do I make the method work?
I tried using different kinds of method, but it still does not work

This code should output numbers instead of characters, every char should be changed into numbers. I used the cellphone keypad as the basis for changing chars into numbers.

Comment: What do you mean "does not work" exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't you use 'A' instead of A ? (for all letters)

Comment: illegal start of expression is the message when I build it

Comment: Looks like you haven't closed main, edit: valid should not be inside main.  Don't define variables like `Key1`. Instead have one variable, `int key` and stick it in the class not in main.

Comment: I suggest you write a short piece of code which you compile and test.  Writing lots of code can leads to many errors to clean up later.

Answer (score 1):

Your `valid` method does print out characters instead of returning them. Apart from the name suggesting that this method does some kind of validation, the `if` cases have to use `return`.
You have defined the keys as integers, but you really want to return characters with the appropriate numbers. And you have to compare against characters, not some static varialbes called A, B, and so on. Your could should be something like this:

```
char Key1 = '1';
char Key2 = '2';
...

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    string input = "0-800-FLO-WERS";
    string output = "";

    for(....)...

}

public static char valid(char input)
{
    if ((input == 'A') || (input == 'B') ... )
        return Key1;
    else if ....
}
```

Comment: when I build it, "public static char valid(char input)" still wasn't accepted, the message was it is an "illegal start of expression"

Answer (score 0):

If you compile and test as you go, you won't write so much code which needs to be fixed later.  Often in translations it is simpler to have some mapping.  Here is one way you can do it

```
public class Main {
    static final String codes = "00000" +
            "11111" +
            "22ABC" +
            "33DEF" +
            "44GHI" +
            "55JKL" +
            "66MNO" +
            "7PQRS" +
            "88TUV" +
            "9WXYZ";

    public static void main(String... ignore) {
        String input = "1-800-FLO-WERS";
        String output = convertTextToDigits(input);
        System.out.println(input + " can be dialed as " + output);
    }

    private static String convertTextToDigits(String input) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
        for(char ch: input.toCharArray()) {
            int pos = codes.indexOf(ch);
            if (pos >=0)
                sb.append(pos/5);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

prints

```
1-800-FLO-WERS can be dialed as 18003569377
```

Comment: This code worked but the '-' must still be in the output
Example 1-800-356-9377

Comment: That is a trivial fix, you just need to add two lines.  I am sure you can work it out. ;)